# is Select Before Update a good approach or vice versa?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am developing an application using normal JDBC connection. The application is developed with Java-Java EE SpringsMVC 3.0 and SQL Server 08 as database. I am required to update a table based on a non primary key column.

Now, before updating the table we had to decide an approach for updating the table, as table may contain huge amount of data. The update Query will be executed in a batch and we are required to design application in a manner wherein it doesn't hog the system resources.
Now, We had to decide between either of the approaches,
  **1. SELECT DATA BEFORE YOU UPDATE** or
  **2. UPDATE DATA AND THEN SELECT MISSING DATA.**

1. Select data before update is only benificial if chances of failure are maximum, i.e. if a batch 100 Query update is executed, and out of which if only 20 rows are updated successfully, then this approach should be taken
2. Update data and then check missing data is benificial only when failure records are far less. By this ap[proach one database select call can be avoided, i.e after a batch update, the count of records updated can be taken and the select query should be executed if and only if theres is a count in mismatch w.r.t no of query.

We are totally unaware about the system on Production environment, but we want to counter for all possibilities and want a faster system. I need your inputs as which is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is 50:50 chance of successful updates or faster selects, its hard to tell from the current scenario mentioned. You probably would want a fuzzy logic approach, getting constant feedback of how many updates were successful over the period of time, and then decide on the basis of that data to either do an update before select or do a select before update.